# Условия в REST. Как верно поступить?

Tags: битрикс, rest

Есть ТЗ. Есть сущности Задачи. Нужно рестом отдавать все задачи.

У задач есть роли.

Делаю - там где я исполнитель

Помогаю, Наблюдатель - где я соисполнитель/наблюдатель

И Поручил - там где я постановщик, НО ГДЕ ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ НЕ Я

как такое условие можно было бы верно реализовать в стандарте Реста?

на ум приходит две вещи

&filter[CREATED_BY]=1&filter[!RESPONSIBLE_ID]=1

и

&filter[VIRTUAL_FIELD_ROLE]=view_role_originator

в первом случае не уверен в правильности решения. во втором случае уже самому не хочется создавать виртуальное поле для фильтра с последующим разбором фильтров на основе роли. хотя второе предпочтительнее с т.з. если вдруг изменится логика ролей, то не нужно будет мучать разработчиков, что с рестом работают, переделывать. но опять же, сколько раз за всю жизнь это может измениться...

Comment: Если вам нужно получить абсолютно все задачи, то почему не использовать `CTasks::GetList`? И настраивайте в нем выбор так как надо и отдавайте потом в REST результат

Comment: рест. не пхп апи. я рест делаю. нужно понять как по стандарту более менее выборки делать. 
п.с. ctask::getlist не стоит использовать

Answer (score 0):

В REST API Битрикс24 за выборку списка задач отвечает метод [`task.item.list`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/item/list.php). Его можно вызывать с пустыми параметрами. Единственное ограничение в нем, так это то, что он по-умолчанию активирует постраничную навигацию и отдает по 50 элементов на страницу.

Пример получения списка всех существующих задач:

```
BX24.callMethod(
    'task.item.list',
    [],
    function(result)
    {
        console.info(result.data());
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ. вопрос был как сделать выборку по условию в ресте. а не как пользоваться рестом задач. я свой рест делаю.